# ssl verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, https, openssl

I have a debian server **Spring Boot** rest service running on it. I have bought ssl from Comodo however never could get it work properly.

```
openssl s_client -connect www.activityfriend.net:8443 -showcerts
```

command gives me the error below:

```
....depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = www.activityfriend.net
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = www.activityfriend.net
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1....
....Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

Contents of my keystore file is below:

```
usertrustrsaaddtrustca.crt, Jan 31, 2019, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): EA:B0:40:68:9A:0D:80:5B:5D:6F:D6:54:FC:16:8C:FF:00:B7:8B:E3
sectigorsadomainvalidationsecureserverca, Jan 31, 2019, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 33:E4:E8:08:07:20:4C:2B:61:82:A3:A1:4B:59:1A:CD:25:B5:F0:DB
af_ssl, Jan 31, 2019, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): C8:C5:DA:2A:83:66:A3:DE:15:05:31:35:C4:35:FD:7F:DE:4F:DE:75
addtrustexternalcaroot, Jan 31, 2019, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 02:FA:F3:E2:91:43:54:68:60:78:57:69:4D:F5:E4:5B:68:85:18:68
```

Let me know if you want to know anything further, Thanks guys.

Comment: The web server needs to have the Comodo Intermediate CA certificate installed along with your purchased Comodo signed certificate.  You will need to look into your web server setup to see how to do that. I'm also assuming the Comodo is in your default ca file as well.

Comment: thank you :) it was exactly as you said !

Comment: Hello there guys. Would you be so kind to change your comments into an accepted answer, please? It makes the solution way easier to find for others who have a similar problem. Thx